# Does a good cleric still have evil spells on their spell list?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, cleric, alignment

It's clear that a cleric can't cast spells with an alignment descriptor opposed to his deity's (so a chaotic good cleric can't cast evil spells nor lawful spells). However, it's not stated anywhere whether these spells are still in their spell list even though they can't cast them, nor does it say anywhere whether they can cast those spells from wands or scrolls (unlike for wizards' specialization schools). I haven't found anything in FAQs or errata to clarify this.

If it's the case that spells are still on their spell list even though they can't cast them, then a cleric would be able to use spell trigger items such as wands to cast those spells — even though I don't think their deity will like this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, they're still on a Cleric's spell list:

> A cleric casts divine spells (the same type of spells available to the
>   druid, paladin, and ranger), which are drawn from the cleric spell
>   list (page 183). However, his alignment may restrict him from **casting**
>   certain spells opposed to his moral or ethical beliefs; see Chaotic,
>   Evil, Good, and Lawful Spells, below.

However, a good Cleric still can't cast a spell with the Evil Subtype from a wand as his alignment restricts him from ***casting*** any such spell. If the text had simply forbade preparing such a spell, then it would be fine.

For wands, DMG pg 245

> **Activation:** Wands use the spell trigger activation method, so ***casting*** a spell from a wand is usually a standard action that doesn't provoke attacks of opportunity.

Comment: But is using a wand considered casting a spell?

Comment: @valepu *"[Wands use the spell trigger activation method, so casting a spell from a wand](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wands.htm)"*

Comment: Oh, and description of "spell triggered" says anyone with spells on her spell list *knows* how to use such item. Still, it does not say she is *allowed to*.