# Are there any cleric spells that qualify for the Minor Shapeshift feat?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, feats, polymorph, feat-qualifications

The Minor Shapeshift reserve feat (*Complete Mage*, p. 45) would be great for my melee-oriented Cleric.

For it to work, you need to have available a "level 4 or higher polymorph spell".

Are there any Cleric spells that qualify (without counting domain spells, since that could force me into some specific domain)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Prepare [*incarnation of evil*](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/mb/20050209a)

**Spells That Have Come Before**, in part, says "For the purpose of adjudicating effects that apply to polymorph spells, any spell whose effect is based on either *alter self* or *polymorph* should be considered to have the polymorph subschool" (*Player's Handbook II* (May 2006) 96 and [here](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ex/20060501a&page=5)).

This means that a cleric can prepare the 5th-level Clr spell ***incarnation of evil*** [trans] (Magic Books of Faerûn column ["*Hate of the Cobra*: Spells from the Church of Set"](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/mb/20050209a) (Feb. 2005))—that says it mostly "functions like *polymorph*"—so as to be benefit from the reserve feat **Minor Shapeshift** (*Complete Mage* 45). Despite its name, the spell lacks the descriptor evil so it can even be cast by a cleric that possesses a good alignment.

Comment: Being able to cast is not required anyway, only to prepare.

Comment: @Mołot I was really only pointing to the disconnect between the spell's evocative name and it lacking the evil descriptor. Still, it doesn't look like the site hosts a question like *Can good clerics prepare evil spells?* yet [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103506/8610) comes close. Might be a good ask (and perhaps for you to even self-answer—if you give it a shot, I'd like to see an answer include a comparison to specialist wizards).